# Avconv generating HUGE metadata over 90mb for 718mb video file

Tags: video-conversion, video-streaming, metadata, libav

This is the metadata file, extracted with Atom box studio:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tok76wospngf854/moov

Video was converted with avconv, info:

```
/usr/local/bin/avconv -version
avconv version 9.4, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 25 2013 20:43:51 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
avconv 9.4
libavutil     52.  3. 0 / 52.  3. 0
libavcodec    54. 35. 0 / 54. 35. 0
libavformat   54. 20. 3 / 54. 20. 3
libavdevice   53.  2. 0 / 53.  2. 0
libavfilter    3.  3. 0 /  3.  3. 0
libavresample  1.  0. 1 /  1.  0. 1
libswscale     2.  1. 1 /  2.  1. 1
```

The avconv command parameters were :

```
'-i', opts.video ,'-strict', 'experimental' ,'-acodec', 'aac' ,'-ac', '2' ,'-ab', '128k' ,'-ar', '44100' ,'-y' ,'-c:v', 'libx264' ,'-qscale', '1' ,'-s', opts.sizes || '640x480' ,'-g', '25' ,'-r', '25' ,path.join(opts.pre_meta_path,status.filename)
```

Later I'll post new atom file and command line used, as well sample of video.

The most space used in moov file is this data:

```
( 249512) Chunk Offset :  0x23A9053B
( 249513) Chunk Offset :  0x23A91D70
( 249514) Chunk Offset :  0x23A91EDF
( 249515) Chunk Offset :  0x23A92699
( 249516) Chunk Offset :  0x23A94112
```

and

```
( 315536) Sample Size :     344
( 315537) Sample Size :     344
( 315538) Sample Size :     345
( 315539) Sample Size :     338
```

A LOT of them! Over 1 million of lines...

Please help. I need to make video stream as smooth as possible. But currently video player and video server passing over 5mb metadata instead of playing video instantly.

What could cause so big metadata file(91.8mb!) for video file of size(718mb) ?

Comment: Without knowing the exact `avconv` command used, I suspect that this will be impossible to answer. It's likely due to the `-loglevel` used, though even then 90+ mb seems excessive.

Comment: I dont understand, why would a final video need a metadata file? These additional files for AVIs are usefull for storing many types of data, but as an output item why would your viewers want them?  When doing VBR encoding (2Pass) or special processing, a seperate file might be produced that is reqired to finish the processing (2nd passes) but the end user has no need or desire for these files.  Mabey this is some kind of NEW thing?  But I can't believe that it would be a really usefull thing, when distributing a simple video to end users.

Answer (score 2):

I have taken a look at your text file, and this is not metadata, but a log file.

The log contains, as far as I can see, one line for each chunk written and even more additional information.

If you have used the loglevel of verbose, this might be a normal occurrence.
Otherwise, maybe the input file had some issues.

Without more information about what you did exactly and especially the parameters of
the aconv command, it would be hard for us to be more specific.

Comment: '-i',  opts.video ,'-strict',  'experimental' ,'-acodec',  'aac' ,'-ac',  '2' ,'-ab',  '128k' ,'-ar',  '44100' ,'-y' ,'-c:v',  'libx264' ,'-qscale',  '1' ,'-s',  opts.sizes || '640x480' ,'-g',  '25' ,'-r',  '25' ,path.join(opts.pre_meta_path,status.filename) here is array of parameters used for avconv

Comment: That's not exactly a command line.

Comment: What the difference? All parameters are visible.

Comment: I have copied these parameters into your post for you about a month ago. Just to remark that having the actual command-line to which this was translated would have made it easier to be sure of what is going on.